# Lift Frobenius generator of Galois group $Gal(l/k)$ of an unramified extension $L/K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

We consider a finite unramified Galois field extension $L/K$ of non-Archimedean local fields with finite 
residue fields $l / k$. 
firstly, some notations: denote by $q \in O_K$ a uniformizer of $O_K$
and $\pi \in O_L$ a uniformizer of $O_L$. Then $n= [L:K]=e \cdot f$ with
$f= [l:k]$ and $(q)O_L= (\pi)^eO_L$.

The theory tells that $Gal(L/K)=Gal(l/k)$. A proof I found in  Fesenko's and Vostokov's 'Local fields and their extensions' works as follows:

1. We construct a map $Gal(L/K) \to Gal(l/k)$ by $\sigma \mapsto \overline{\sigma}$. is well defined, because $\sigma(O_L)=O_L$ and $\sigma(\pi O_L)=\pi O_L$
2. prove this map is surjective
3. use that the extension is unramified: $\vert Gal(L/K)= [L:K]=[l:k]= Gal(l/k)$

Although I understand the proof, one thing I sorely miss: how the lifts of elements of $Gal(l/k)$ explicitly look like?

More precisely, from Galois theory of finite fields we know $Gal(l/k)$ is generated by relative Frobenius $\bar{F}: l \to l, a \mapsto a^d$ with $d = \vert k \vert = p^s $ ($p$ is the characteristic of $k$). As $Gal(L/K)=Gal(l/k)$, the unique preimage ("lift") $F: L \to L$ of the relative Frobenius $\bar{F}$ generates $Gal(L/K)$.

*Question*: Is there any way to describe *explicitly* how the lift $F$ looks like, ie how it acts on elements of $L$? Can we find any canonical generators of $L$ on which the action of $F$ can be described? Or is this lift only an "abstract" construction without any explicite description?

My idea was - since $l = k(\zeta)$ for a appropriate root of unity $\zeta$ - to lift this root with Hensel's lemma. but I not see any reason why this lift of the root generates $L$ as $K$-algebra .

Comment: Your idea is right. The degree of $\zeta$ over $K$ is the same as that of the corresponding element over $k$ and so comparing degrees you get the result.

Comment: But wouldn't this imply that for every finite unramified extension $L/K$ the field $L$ is genrated by a root of unity. That looks wrong to me.

Comment: It isn't wrong, that is exactly the case. Eg concretely over $\mathbb Q_p$ the unramified extension of degree $n$ is obtained by by adjoining a primitive $p^n-1^{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: It is the completeness (Hensel lemma) which implies that unramified extensions are generated by roots of unity. If $a\bmod (\pi_L)$ has order $ m$ in $l$ then $\zeta=\lim_{n\to \infty} a^{p^n}$ has order $m$ in $L$. If $m=|l|-1$ then $l=k(a)$ so $L$ and $K(\zeta)$ have the same residue field, if they have the same uniformizer (ie. if $L/K$ is unramified) then $L=K$.

Comment: @reuns: in last line you were going to say $L= K(\zeta)$?